# How can I make this link cover a larger area without revealing the words underneath?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, navbar

If you hover over the words in the navbar you can see they do a little transition. Now, for this hover effect to happen you don't need to put the cursor directly on the word, you can put the cursor anywhere under or above the word and it will still activate the transition.

Now here's the problem, to go to a different page you have to click directly on the word. I want to be able to click on the link even if my mouse is slightly above/below the word.

Here's the [JSFIDDLE link](https://jsfiddle.net/by7pw771/#&togetherjs=p5CwRzglOm)

HTML

```css
body {
    background-image:url('../images/geometry2.jpg');
}

.homeBody {
    display:none;
}

header {
    padding:0 !important;
    margin:0 !important;
    font-family:"Raleway", sans-serif !important;
}

header nav a {
    color:#fff !important;   
    font-family:"Raleway", sans-serif !important;
}

.navbar-nav > li {
    color:#fff !important;   
    font-family:"Raleway", sans-serif !important;
}

header nav li:hover a, header nav li.active a {
    color:#ecf0f1 !important;   
}

header nav li:hover, header nav li.active {
    color:#ecf0f1 !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color:#fff;   
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color:#fff; 
}

.linkContain {
    position:absolute;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-nav > li, .menu-small header .navbar-nav > li, .touch header .navbar-nav > li {
        background:#0e6957;
    }
}
.title {
    width:100%;
    margin-top:120px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'Lato', sans-serif, serif;
    font-size:50px;
    color:#2d2d2d;
}

.images-3 {
    margin-top:30px;
}

.incenseTypes {
    width:80%;
    margin:40px auto 0 auto;
}

.smolder {
    width:80%;
    margin:40px auto 0 auto;
}

.smolder img {
    width:100%;
}

.view-button {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    background:#16a085;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:24px;
}

.view-button:hover {
    background:#0e6957;
}

.aboutSection {
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
}

.infoTitle {
    font-family:'Lato', sans-serif, serif;
}

.infoTitle2 {
    font-size:35px;
    font-family:'Lato', sans-serif, serif;
}

.infoBullets {
    font-size:18px;
}

.infoIntro {
    font-size:18px;
}

.infoLink {
    color:#3aa5d2;
}

footer {
    height:100px;
    background:#148d75;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:23px;
}

footer a {
    color:#fff;
}

footer a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#4cbceb;
}

.copyrightRow {
    margin-top:15px;
}

ul.social-buttons {
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.social-buttons {
    text-align:center;
}

.fa-facebook {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display:block;
    background-image:url('../images/home/icons/facebook.svg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    transition:all 0.4s;
}

.fa-facebook:hover {
    background-image:url('../images/home/icons/facebookHover.svg');
}

.fa-twitter {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display:block;
    background-image:url('../images/home/icons/twitter.svg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    transition:all 0.4s;
}

.fa-twitter:hover {
    background-image:url('../images/home/icons/twitterHover.svg');
}

.topScentsTitle {
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:35px;
    color:#2d2d2d;
}

.topScents {
    width:80%;
    margin:20px auto 0 auto;
}

.buyNow {
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    font-size:25px;
    color:#fff;
}

.buyNow {
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#148d75;
    border:none;
    padding:0px !important;
    transition:all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition:all 0.3s
}

.buyNow:hover { 
    background:#0e6957;
}

.moreInfo {
    width:80%;
    margin:5px auto 0 -4px;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#34495e;
    padding:0px !important;
    border:none;
    transition:all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition:all 0.3s
}

.moreInfo:hover {
    background:#2c3e50;
}

.btn {
    padding:0;
}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding:0;  
}


a {
  -webkit-transition: color 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: color 200ms linear;
  transition: color 200ms linear;
}
body {
  /*background:@bg-light;*/
  background: #fff;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #999999;
  outline: none;
}
body.home {
  background: #fff;
}
*,
a,
button,
input,
*:focus,
a:focus,
button:focus,
input:focus {
  outline: none!important;
}
.centered {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.neuton {
  font-family: "Neuton", serif;
}
.neuton_bold {
  font-family: "Neuton", serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.neuton_italic {
  font-family: "Neuton", serif;
  font-style: italic;
}
.rale {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}
.rale_medium {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.rale_bold {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  font-family: "Neuton", serif;
  color: #9a8e87;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 45px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 22px;
}
a {
  color: #666;
}
a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #333333;
}
.touch .touch-hide {
  display: none;
}
.no-touch .touch-show {
  display: none;
}
.touch .touch-show {
  display: block;
}
.btn {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  padding: 15px 45px;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
  background: #e2dbd7;
  color: #fff;
}
.btn:hover,
.btn:focus,
.btn:active,
.btn.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #b5afac;
}
.btn-red {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #cc3300;
}
.btn-red:hover,
.btn-red:focus,
.btn-red:active,
.btn-red.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-red {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #a32900;
}
.btn-red:active,
.btn-red.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-red {
  background-image: none;
}
.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}
.control-label {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #9a8e87;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.form-control {
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  background: none;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  color: #b7b7b7;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 1px solid #cac2b5;
}
.form-control:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #7c7c7c !important;
}
.form-control.required {
  border-color: #cc3300!important;
  border-left-width: 7px;
}
.control-label.required {
  color: #cc3300;
}
.selectizer.required .selectizer-label {
  border-color: #cc3300;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
.navbar-default {
  height: 102px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e7e6;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
  padding: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
  height: 102px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
.navbar-nav > li  > a {
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  background: #148d75 !important;
  -webkit-transition: height 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: height 200ms linear;
  transition: height 200ms linear;
}
header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header .navbar-collapse {
  float: right;
}
header nav {
  float: right;
  border-right: 1px solid #E9E7E6;
  /* background: @bg-light;*/

}
header nav li {
  /*border-left: 1px solid rgba(229,227,225,0); border-right: 1px solid rgba(229,227,225,0);*/
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid @line-light;*/
  cursor: pointer;
}
header nav a {
  color: #dad1cd!important;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
}

header nav a span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}
header nav li:hover,
header nav li.active {
  /*background: @nav-light-hover-bg;*/

  border-left-color: #e9e7e6;
  border-right-color: #e9e7e6;
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid @bg-light;*/

}
header nav li:hover a,
header nav li.active a {
  color: #a49993!important;
}
header nav li.active {
  background: #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #e9e7e6;
  border-right: 1px solid #e9e7e6;
}
header nav li:not(.active) a span::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  content: attr(data-hover);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
header nav li:not(.active):hover a span,
header nav li:not(.active) a:focus span {
  -webkit-transform: translatey(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translatey(-100%);
  transform: translatey(-100%);
}
header .user {
  float: right;
}
header .user li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  border-right: 0;
}
header .user li a {
  height: 102px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 43px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none!important;
}
header .user li a .mask {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
header .user li a .mask span {
  display: block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 32px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  transition-delay: .05s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .05s;
}
header .user li a .num {
  color: #cc3300;
}
header .user li a:hover .mask span,
header .user li a.active .mask span {
  transition-delay: 0;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -16px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0px, -16px);
  transform: translate(0px, -16px);
  /*margin-top: -16px*/

}
header .user li.profile {
  margin-right: 2px;
}
header .user li.profile a .mask span {
  background: url('../images/header-user-light.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
header .user li.cart a .mask span {
  background: url('../images/header-cart-light.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
header .user li.cart a.active .mask span {
  background-image: url("../images/header-cart-light-active.png");
}
header .user li.lang a {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: padding-top 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: padding-top 200ms linear;
  transition: padding-top 200ms linear;
}
header .user li.lang span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #e9e7e6;
  text-align: center;
  color: #e9e7e6;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}
header .user li.lang span:hover {
  color: #a49993;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-color: #a49993;
}
.navbar-nav > li.li-language,
.touch header .navbar-nav > li.li-language {
  border-top: 1px solid #f0edeb !important;
}
.home.menu-abs header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0 !important;
}
.navbar-collapse.in nav,
.navbar-collapse.collapsing nav {
  float: none;
  border-right: none;
  padding-right: 0;
  height: auto;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .disabled > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #bfb6b1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #a49993;
}
.navbar-nav > li:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}
.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
#header-logo {
  display: block;
  width: 170px;
  height: 102px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: height 200ms linear;
  transition: height 300ms linear;
}
#header-logo span {
  display: block;
  width: 170px;
  height: 102px;
  z-index:-1;
  position: relative;
  background: url('../images/logo.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  -webkit-transition: margin 200ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: margin 200ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: margin 200ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: margin 200ms ease-in-out;
  transition: margin 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding:0;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <header class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <a class="navbar-brand" id="header-logo" href="http://folksverona.com/"><span>Folks Verona</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
   <ul>
        <li class="profile">
                    <a href="http://folksverona.com/user">
                        <span class="mask"><span>Profile</span></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
    <li class="cart">
                    <a href="http://folksverona.com/shop/cart" id="bt-cart" >
                        <span class="mask"><span>Cart</span></span>
                        <span class="num"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
        <li class="lang hidden-xs">
                    <a href="http://folksverona.it"><span>Help</span></a>
                </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
   <nav class="clearfix">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li class=""><a href="#home"><span data-hover="Home">Home</span></a></li>
     <li class=""><a href="#shop"><span data-hover="Shop">Shop</span></a></li>
     <li class=""><a href="#test"><span data-hover="Test">Test</span></a></li>
     <li class=""><a href="#about"><span data-hover="About">About</span></a></li>
     <li class=""><a href="#contact"><span data-hover="Contact">Contact</span></a></li>
     <li class="visible-xs li-language"><a href="http://folksverona.it"><span data-hover="IT">IT</span></a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </div>
</header>
```

I suggest checking out the [JSFIDDLE link](https://jsfiddle.net/by7pw771/#&togetherjs=p5CwRzglOm) because it is more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
body {
    background-image:url('../images/geometry2.jpg');
}

.homeBody {
    display:none;
}

header {
    padding:0 !important;
    margin:0 !important;
    font-family:"Raleway", sans-serif !important;
}

header nav a {
    color:#fff !important;   
    font-family:"Raleway", sans-serif !important;
}

.navbar-nav > li {
    color:#fff !important;   
    font-family:"Raleway", sans-serif !important;
}

header nav li:hover a, header nav li.active a {
    color:#ecf0f1 !important;   
}

header nav li:hover, header nav li.active {
    color:#ecf0f1 !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color:#fff;   
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color:#fff; 
}

.linkContain {
    position:absolute;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-nav > li, .menu-small header .navbar-nav > li, .touch header .navbar-nav > li {
        background:#0e6957;
    }
}
.title {
    width:100%;
    margin-top:120px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'Lato', sans-serif, serif;
    font-size:50px;
    color:#2d2d2d;
}

.images-3 {
    margin-top:30px;
}

.incenseTypes {
    width:80%;
    margin:40px auto 0 auto;
}

.smolder {
    width:80%;
    margin:40px auto 0 auto;
}

.smolder img {
    width:100%;
}

.view-button {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    background:#16a085;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:24px;
}

.view-button:hover {
    background:#0e6957;
}

.aboutSection {
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
}

.infoTitle {
    font-family:'Lato', sans-serif, serif;
}

.infoTitle2 {
    font-size:35px;
    font-family:'Lato', sans-serif, serif;
}

.infoBullets {
    font-size:18px;
}

.infoIntro {
    font-size:18px;
}

.infoLink {
    color:#3aa5d2;
}

footer {
    height:100px;
    background:#148d75;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:23px;
}

footer a {
    color:#fff;
}

footer a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#4cbceb;
}

.copyrightRow {
    margin-top:15px;
}

ul.social-buttons {
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.social-buttons {
    text-align:center;
}

.fa-facebook {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display:block;
    background-image:url('../images/home/icons/facebook.svg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    transition:all 0.4s;
}

.fa-facebook:hover {
    background-image:url('../images/home/icons/facebookHover.svg');
}

.fa-twitter {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display:block;
    background-image:url('../images/home/icons/twitter.svg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    transition:all 0.4s;
}

.fa-twitter:hover {
    background-image:url('../images/home/icons/twitterHover.svg');
}

.topScentsTitle {
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:35px;
    color:#2d2d2d;
}

.topScents {
    width:80%;
    margin:20px auto 0 auto;
}

.buyNow {
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    font-size:25px;
    color:#fff;
}

.buyNow {
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#148d75;
    border:none;
    padding:0px !important;
    transition:all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition:all 0.3s
}

.buyNow:hover { 
    background:#0e6957;
}

.moreInfo {
    width:80%;
    margin:5px auto 0 -4px;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#34495e;
    padding:0px !important;
    border:none;
    transition:all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition:all 0.3s
}

.moreInfo:hover {
    background:#2c3e50;
}

.btn {
    padding:0;
}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding:0;  
}


a {
  -webkit-transition: color 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: color 200ms linear;
  transition: color 200ms linear;
}
body {
  /*background:@bg-light;*/
  background: #fff;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #999999;
  outline: none;
}
body.home {
  background: #fff;
}
*,
a,
button,
input,
*:focus,
a:focus,
button:focus,
input:focus {
  outline: none!important;
}
.centered {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.neuton {
  font-family: "Neuton", serif;
}
.neuton_bold {
  font-family: "Neuton", serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.neuton_italic {
  font-family: "Neuton", serif;
  font-style: italic;
}
.rale {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}
.rale_medium {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.rale_bold {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  font-family: "Neuton", serif;
  color: #9a8e87;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 45px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 22px;
}
a {
  color: #666;
}
a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #333333;
}
.touch .touch-hide {
  display: none;
}
.no-touch .touch-show {
  display: none;
}
.touch .touch-show {
  display: block;
}
.btn {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  padding: 15px 45px;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
  background: #e2dbd7;
  color: #fff;
}
.btn:hover,
.btn:focus,
.btn:active,
.btn.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #b5afac;
}
.btn-red {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #cc3300;
}
.btn-red:hover,
.btn-red:focus,
.btn-red:active,
.btn-red.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-red {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #a32900;
}
.btn-red:active,
.btn-red.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-red {
  background-image: none;
}
.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}
.control-label {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #9a8e87;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.form-control {
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  background: none;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  color: #b7b7b7;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 1px solid #cac2b5;
}
.form-control:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #7c7c7c !important;
}
.form-control.required {
  border-color: #cc3300!important;
  border-left-width: 7px;
}
.control-label.required {
  color: #cc3300;
}
.selectizer.required .selectizer-label {
  border-color: #cc3300;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
.navbar-default {
  height: 102px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e7e6;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
  padding: 0;
}
.navbar-nav > li  > a {
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  background: #148d75 !important;
  -webkit-transition: height 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: height 200ms linear;
  transition: height 200ms linear;
}
header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header .navbar-collapse {
  float: right;
}
header nav {
  float: right;
  border-right: 1px solid #E9E7E6;
  /* background: @bg-light;*/

}
header nav li {
  /*border-left: 1px solid rgba(229,227,225,0); border-right: 1px solid rgba(229,227,225,0);*/
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid @line-light;*/
  cursor: pointer;
}
header nav a {
  color: #dad1cd!important;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
}

header nav a span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}
header nav li:hover,
header nav li.active {
  /*background: @nav-light-hover-bg;*/

  border-left-color: #e9e7e6;
  border-right-color: #e9e7e6;
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid @bg-light;*/

}
header nav li:hover a,
header nav li.active a {
  color: #a49993!important;
}
header nav li.active {
  background: #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #e9e7e6;
  border-right: 1px solid #e9e7e6;
}
header nav li:not(.active) a span::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  content: attr(data-hover);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
header nav li:not(.active):hover a span,
header nav li:not(.active) a:focus span {
 /* -webkit-transform: translatey(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translatey(-100%);
  transform: translatey(-100%);*/
}
header .user {
  float: right;
}
header .user li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  border-right: 0;
}
header .user li a {
  height: 102px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 43px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none!important;
}
header .user li a .mask {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
header .user li a .mask span {
  display: block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 32px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  transition-delay: .05s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .05s;
}
header .user li a .num {
  color: #cc3300;
}
header .user li a:hover .mask span,
header .user li a.active .mask span {
  transition-delay: 0;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -16px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0px, -16px);
  transform: translate(0px, -16px);
  /*margin-top: -16px*/

}
header .user li.profile {
  margin-right: 2px;
}
header .user li.profile a .mask span {
  background: url('../images/header-user-light.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
header .user li.cart a .mask span {
  background: url('../images/header-cart-light.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
header .user li.cart a.active .mask span {
  background-image: url("../images/header-cart-light-active.png");
}
header .user li.lang a {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: padding-top 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: padding-top 200ms linear;
  transition: padding-top 200ms linear;
}
header .user li.lang span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #e9e7e6;
  text-align: center;
  color: #e9e7e6;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}
header .user li.lang span:hover {
  color: #a49993;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-color: #a49993;
}
.navbar-nav > li.li-language,
.touch header .navbar-nav > li.li-language {
  border-top: 1px solid #f0edeb !important;
}
.home.menu-abs header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0 !important;
}
.navbar-collapse.in nav,
.navbar-collapse.collapsing nav {
  float: none;
  border-right: none;
  padding-right: 0;
  height: auto;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .disabled > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #bfb6b1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #a49993;
}
.navbar-nav > li:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}
.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
#header-logo {
  display: block;
  width: 170px;
  height: 102px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: height 200ms linear;
  transition: height 300ms linear;
}
#header-logo span {
  display: block;
  width: 170px;
  height: 102px;
  z-index:-1;
  position: relative;
  background: url('../images/logo.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  -webkit-transition: margin 200ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: margin 200ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: margin 200ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: margin 200ms ease-in-out;
  transition: margin 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding:0;  
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #777;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right span {
    padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <header class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <a class="navbar-brand" id="header-logo" href="http://folksverona.com/"><span>Folks Verona</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
   <ul>
        <li class="profile">
                    <a href="http://folksverona.com/user">
                        <span class="mask"><span>Profile</span></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
    <li class="cart">
                    <a href="http://folksverona.com/shop/cart" id="bt-cart" >
                        <span class="mask"><span>Cart</span></span>
                        <span class="num"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
        <li class="lang hidden-xs">
                    <a href="http://folksverona.it"><span>Help</span></a>
                </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
   <nav class="clearfix">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li class=""><a href="#home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
     <li class=""><a href="#shop"><span>Shop</span></a></li>
     <li class=""><a href="#test"><span>Test</span></a></li>
     <li class=""><a href="#about"><span>About</span></a></li>
     <li class=""><a href="#contact"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
     <li class="visible-xs li-language"><a href="http://folksverona.it"><span>IT</span></a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I would like to keep the effect on the text if possible. It looks fine with just a color transition, but I really do like the little animation. Is there any way to keep the animation but still have the full size links?